# Why is my c# console application hanging when I try to exit?

Tags: c#, exit

I have a console app that sometimes does NOT exit when I issue the following 2 lines:

```
        File.AppendAllText(@"\\bbd\FLog", "Halting: " + DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss") + "\n");
        System.Environment.Exit(0);
```

The halting message IS written to disk, but the application is still alive in taskmanager.

The application does use a threading timer:

```
GetRecordsTimer = new System.Threading.Timer(new TimerCallback(GetRecordsCallBack), null, 60000, 0);
```

That is declared as:

```
public static System.Threading.Timer GetRecordsTimer;
```

BUT my understanding of Environment.Exit(0) is that is kills everything (all threads) and then exits.

Note: not only is the application still alive, but my log file FLog appears to be in use...

Could it be that AppendAllText is somehow not finished if I exit immediately afterwards?

Comment: Environment.Exit does not terminate threads, it just terminates your application.

Comment: Please create a [mre].

Comment: @TonyAbrams If some threads are running, the application is not terminated, is it?

Comment: @TonyAbrams Terminating a process results in the termination of every thread in that process.  If those threads cannot be terminated, the process cannot be, either.

Comment: Its a [known problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18036863/why-does-environment-exit-not-terminate-the-program-any-more) in Windows that came back a few times.  But not so likely in a console mode app, next likely cause is crummy anti-malware with a "deep scan" feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My thought based on what you are describing is that the network write operation to `\\bbd` is not completing.

If you want to log and exit, but exit is more important than logging, perhaps try something like this:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(state => {
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
    Environment.Exit(0);
});
File.AppendAllText(@"\\bbd\FLog", "Halting: " + DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss") + "\n");
```

This way, your process will exit in 2 seconds no matter what; even if your log operation never completes.

A more elegant solution might quit as soon as the log operation completes OR after a timeout, but my code is just for an example

Comment: I like that. I understand it might be better to use System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill(), instead of Environment.Exit() if not on main thread? Do you agree?

Comment: Environment.Exit() documentation states: "Exit terminates an application immediately, even if other threads are running."  `Process.Kill` will probably do the same thing, but it is intended to kill *a* process, whereas `Environment.Exit()` is intended to kill the *current process*.  I would favor `Environment.Exit()`, less moving parts.

Comment: Understood. Could the fact I am immediately exiting after the AppendAllText be somehow causing the file not to be released?